# How can I pre-populate data in room db with multiple tables?

Tags: android, database, android-studio, android-room

**Here's what I am thinking:**
What I want is I want to create multiple tables in my database and get the data from those tables separately to display it to the UI.
But I tried it myself I was getting an error saying that either the database is not available or the table not found.

Comment: What's the problem? There are [plenty of resources](https://www.google.com/search?q=pre-populate+room+database&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS989US989&oq=pre-populate+room+database&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l6j69i60.3387j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) out there already for doing this.

Comment: there is a detailed guide on how to do that in developers website with exact same wording https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate refer that first

Comment: Also, FWIW, I cover that subject in [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/Room/pages/chap-package-001.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Room).